# Long string from jsp javascript to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I need to send some big string (5000 characters including '=' and '&'), dynamic array and short string to servlet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var categories= new Array();
var tit= document.getElementById("title");
var cont= document.getElementById("content");
</script>
<input type="text" id="title" style="width:250px"/>
<textarea id="content" style="width:400px"></textarea>
```

I thought to try xmlhttprequest with POST, but 'content' cotrol can contain '=' and '&'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent(param)` function:

Your case: You need to encode `cont` like the following `encodeURIComponent(cont)`. This will escape '=' and '&' and other special chars.

For example

```
var url = 'http://myserver.com?content=' + encodeURIComponent(cont);
```

Comment: No. Server will automatically decode it. You will get original content at server site.